# Share EF connection string from subproject in the main project

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two projects

```
MyProject //MVC 3 app
MyProject.DAL //Class Library project type
```

Inside `MyProject.DAL` there is a folder `EntityModels` which contains generated entity (EF Code-First approach):

```
namespace MyProject.DAL.EntityModels
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class myEntities : DbContext
    {
        public myEntities() : base("name=myEntities")
        {
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

app.config:

```
 <add name="myEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModels.DBMainModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModels.DBMainModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModels.DBMainModel.msl;provider=..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

then, I want to use that entity in my `MyProject` project, so I add the same connection string in the `web.config` file.

But,  I get the `Unable to load the specified metadata resource.` error. I tried make some modifications in the `web.config` like

```
<add name="myEntities"
connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyProject.DAL.EntityModels.DBMainModel.csdl|
                           res://*/MyProject.DAL.EntityModels.DBMainModel.ssdl|
                           res://*/MyProject.DAL.EntityModels.DBMainModel.msl;provider=..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

<add name="myEntities"
connectionString="metadata=res://MyProject.DAL.EntityModels.DBMainModel.csdl|
                           res://MyProject.DAL.EntityModels.DBMainModel.ssdl|
                           res://MyProject.DAL.EntityModels.DBMainModel.msl;provider=..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />


<add name="myEntities"
connectionString="metadata=res://MyProject.DAL/EntityModels.DBMainModel.csdl|
                           res://MyProject.DAL/EntityModels.DBMainModel.ssdl|
                           res://MyProject.DAL/EntityModels.DBMainModel.msl;provider=..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

but nothing works. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's code-first, you should put pure connectionString value in your appropriate .config file (You're dealing with `SqlClient` not `EntityClient`).
To find out more about ConnectionString values, take a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/.

For SQL Server databases, basically it is like below:

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="Data Source=myServerName\myInstanceName;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```